# Usage of Was vs is?

Tags: word-choice

Does the choice of present or past tense ("It is..." vs "It was...") make a difference to these sentences?

> - It is not too long ago when humanity learned to live in groups and developed principles to govern themselves.
> - It was not long ago when humanity learned to live in groups and developed principles to govern themselves.

Comment: Both are idiomatic in that context and it is difficult to think of any nuanced difference in meaning.

Comment: I slightly disagree with @WS2, the top one sounds wrong to me. "Ago" means in the past, which doesn't fit with the present "is." Maybe it's more accepted in BrE. Sounds somewhat better if you put a "now" in there, "It is not too long ago now that…" but I'd still recommend just using "was."

Comment: To me "was" sound more natural and implies looking back over history. Whereas "is" has the feel that you are looking at a timeline of history in a textbook, or is something that might be said by a time traveller.

Comment: @Kevin I'm British, and I agree with you that "It is not too long ago ..." doesn't quite sound right.

Comment: The first one is a general statement which doesn't make one look for more information, whereas the second one seems to have been used in a context, and leave one to think "so what?"

Comment: First one sounds very clumsy. "It is not too long since humanity learned..." maybe.

Answer (score -1):

You are talking about something that happened in the past, but that comment is explained in the present,  I think is better to use the present tense.